# How to pass value from jquery ajax to servlet, I am facing 404 error while passing url

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

*JQuery Code : How to call servlet class from HTML Page using ajax, I have written some piece of code below to call servlet class which having in same java package, I am facing 404 page not found error

```
//checking page to be ready for event
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
      //runs after event occured on first dropbox
       $('#inpmfudorgId').change(function()
       {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          //servlet file name to which i want to connect
          url: "FileConnection",
          //throw alert if connection established
          success: function(result)
          {
            alert("called");
          },
          //alert if it couldnt make connection with servlet              
          type: "POST",
          error: function(xhr)
          {
          alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

*Web.xml    : I have define actual path in web.xml like below

```
<servlet>
  //Name of File
  <servlet-name>FileConnection</servlet-name>
  //Servlet File Path
  <servlet-class>in.mbs.fileupload.ad_forms.FileConnection</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileConnection</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/FileConnection</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: A 404 means the URL you're calling is wrong or not recognised. You need to check your server configuration

Comment: Try to access this url from web browser directly to confirm this url is reachable or not. 404 error means, it's not able to reach that url.

Comment: Your jQuery code doesn't know what FileConnection means. If your application is running locally, it will have a url that looks like `http://localhost:<your_port>/FileConnection` Try making the AJAX url point to the http url of your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JQuery code is correct. 
To resolve the 404 exception create a new servlet(dummy) FormServlet in a com.formselection package and add the below mapping in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.formselection.FormServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/FormServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Also, replace url: "FileConnection" to **url: "FormServlet"** in JQuery code.
Check the jquery code is running fine or not. Later on replace the dummy name of servlet.